# getline() function in C++ does not work

Tags: c++, file, getline

i wrote a code in C++ where it opens a .txt file and reads its contents, think of it as a  (MAC address database), each mac address is delimited by a (.), my problem is after i search the file for total number of lines , iam unable to return the pointer to the initial position of the file in here i use `seekg() and tellg()` to manipulate the pointer to the file.

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int i = 0;
string str1;

ifstream file;
file.open ("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\MAC.txt");  


 //this section calculates the no. of lines

while (!file.eof() )
{
  getline (file,str1); 
 for (int z =0 ; z<=15; z++)
 if (str1[z] == '.')
 i++;   
}


file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
getline(file,str2);

cout << "the number of lines are " << i << endl; 
cout << str2 << endl;

file.close();


      getchar();
      return 0;
      }
```

and here is the contents of the MAC.txt file:

0090-d0f5-723a.

0090-d0f2-87hf.

b048-7aae-t5t5.

000e-f4e1-xxx2.

1c1d-678c-9db3.

0090-d0db-f923.

d85d-4cd3-a238.

1c1d-678c-235d.

`here the the output of the code is supposed to be the first MAC address but it returns the last one .`

Comment: We need "`while (!file.eof())` is wrong!" permanently pinned to the top of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes.  The problem is that there are sites out there which use it in their examples, and claim to know C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file.seekg(0,ios::end);
```

I believe you wanted `file.seekg(0,ios::beg);` here.

Zero offset from the end (`ios::end`) is the end of the file. The read fails and you're left with the last value you read in the buffer.

Also, once you've reached `eof`, you should manually reset it with `file.clear();` before you seek:

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
getline(file,str2);
```

The error would have been easier to catch if you checked for errors when you perform file operations. See Kerrek SB's answer for examples.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, yeah iam already using ios::beg but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't know about the `file.clear()`, the problem is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is making all sorts of mistakes. You never check any error states!

This is how it should go:

```
std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\MAC.txt");  

for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
// the loop exits when "file" is in an error state
{
    /* whatever condition */ i++;   
}

file.clear();                 // reset error state
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // rewind

std::string firstline;
if (!(std::getline(file, firstline)) { /* error */ }

std::cout << "The first line is: " << firstline << "\n";
```